# Resolve object from routing resolve to controller in angular

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have routing config like following

```
var app = angular.module("productApp",["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",
        {
            templateUrl : "views/home.html",
            controller :  "homeController"
        }).
        when("/add/:productId?",
        {
            templateUrl : "views/products/add.html",
            controller :  "productController",
            resolve : {
                checkId: function($q,$timeout,$http,$route,$location){
                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    var productData = {};
                    var productId = $route.current.params.productId;
                    $http.get("model/checkProductById.php?productId="+productId).then(function(data){
                        if(data.data.status==1){
                            productData = data.data.data;
                            // console.log("afterthis");
                            // console.log(productData);
                            defer.resolve(productData);
                            return productData;
                        }else{
                            //defer.reject();
                            $location.path("/");

                        }
                    });

                    return defer.promise;
                }
            }
        }).
        when("/products",
        {
            templateUrl:    "views/products/view.html",
            controller:     "productController"
        });
});
app.controller("homeController",function($scope){
    $scope.model = {
        message:"Hello World"
    };
});
```

Check Id in resolve check if product id is valid via $http  service.I also checking and returning product object in resolve object.

My controller :

```
app.controller("productController",function($scope, $http,productService,$routeParams,checkId){

    $scope.productId = $routeParams.productId;
    $scope.model = {
        message:"Hello World from products"
    };
}));
```

When i pass checkId in controller it giving error of unknown provider.
How can i get resolve object in controller.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, you can't inject this specific function in your controller. Why do you need this exactly function in your controller?

Comment: @L.Figueredo In resolve object i am getting product related data and i have to set that data in view after resolve. I can get data again by calling $http again. But i want to get product data at the same time of resolving.Is there is any way?

Comment: When i console.log($scope). I can see the value in $scope.$resolve.checkId.  But when i call it throw error

Comment: You can see if this resolve your situation: https://johnpapa.net/route-resolve-and-controller-activate-in-angularjs/ - I think this explains about what you need.

Comment: Thanks : I am also i think following second route approach. Instead of creating service i am directly defining it. Let see what happen when i create service

Comment: Let me know if this resolves your problem :D

Comment: @L.Figueredo  I got the solution via $route approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally get the data via $route with isDefined condition

```
app.controller("productController",function($scope, $http,productService,$routeParams,$route){

        $scope.productId = $routeParams.productId;
        $scope.model = {
            message:"Hello World from products"
        };
        if(angular.isDefined($route.current)){
            console.log($route.current.locals.checkId);
        }
        });
```